# Setting SOAP Envelope Payload in a Custom Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am writing a proxy service in WSO2 ESB that accepts a JSON payload and performs some transformations (to a SOAP message) that are quite complex, so we are writing the transformation logic in a Custom Mediator.

As you can see, my custom mediator class sets a property in the message context, and the proxy flow extracts this property and sets the payload (using a Javascript API that I could find).

This results in my SOAP message being "double wrapped" in two envelope tags, and I need to use an enricher with a XPath expression to remove the outer envelope/body tags.

**Is it possible to set the XML payload within the custom mediator, thus avoiding to read a property and writing the XML payload in the proxy flow?**

The proxy code is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="stackOverflowProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="jms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <!-- process incoming request in custom class. the payload is a JSON object -->
      <class name="stackOverflow.CustomMediator"/>
          <!-- set registration xml string as xml payload -->
          <script language="js"><![CDATA[mc.setPayloadXML(new XML(mc.getProperty('mediatorPayload')));]]></script>
          <enrich>
            <source clone="true"
              xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xpath="$body//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*"/>
            <target type="body"/>
          </enrich>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

And this is the Custom Mediator class:

```
package stackOverflow;

// imports ...

public class CustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {

public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
    //messageContext has a json object property
    //message is processed and transformed to a SOAPEnvelope (namespaces omitted for simplicity)
    //soapEnvelopeString = <Envelope><Body><tag>value</tag></Body></Envelope> 
    messageContext.setProperty("mediatorPayload", soapEnvelope.toString());     
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom mediator you are setting entire soap message in to a property and in script mediator setting it as payload of the soap message. thats why you are getting double soap env.

in your class mediator set only the body payload to property and then insert that value as payload in main flow using script will solve your issue.

```
package stackOverflow;

// imports ...

public class CustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {

public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
    //messageContext has a json object property
    //message is processed and transformed to a SOAPEnvelope (namespaces omitted for simplicity)
    //**soapPayload = <tag>value</tag>** 
    messageContext.setProperty("mediatorPayload", soapPayload);     
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jenananthan. I understand why it happens. My payload has many properties in it, so it's a lot better if I could just set the payload XML from the mediator class itself. Otherwise I have to write a property, then read a property, then copy it to the payload object. Seems like a waste of memory and computation, and also less elegant.

Comment: you can refer the code of payloadfacotry mediator to set the payload in custom mediator

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/transform/PayloadFactoryMediator.java#L166